# C#. Enumerations

Tags: c#, enums

My problem is that my application and VS freeze if I use enumeration member with the name `ProcessStateChanged`.

I can't neither stop debug, nor kill process and that continues for about 4 minutes.

I would be grateful if you could just explain me why that happens.

Thanks!

Comment: how about changing the name?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's nearly impossible to give you an answer.  Stack Overflow is not a crystal ball....

Comment: @Guy is that one a reserved word? looked in google but didn't find anything htere. 

Ivan: You would need to post a few examples of the code where / how you use that enumeration else there is not enough information there to help you out

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: No, your compiler would throw an error if it was a reserved word and you wouldnt compile. I would be almost 99.9999999999% certain its go nothing todo with the name. Thats like coming into work and finding your PC wont turn on so blaming the fact your called Ivan. Post some code and we can find the infinate loop you most definatly have somewhere in your code.

Comment: I strongly doubt that the enum `ProcessStateChanged` is responsible for the freeze.

Comment: try start studio in safe mode - any plugins?

Answer (score 1):

You could start by checking the Event Viewer of windows for any error messages and also the log of Visual Studio.